# how save the current level

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am making a game with 50+ levels. I can't seem to be able to save the game so that when the user later opens the game, it will be on the same level they the user left off at. I use the fallowing code to transition from level to level.

```
let leveltwo = levelTwo(fileNamed: "levelTwo")
leveltwo?.scaleMode = .aspectFill
self.view?.presentScene(leveltwo!, transition:SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.1))
```

I also have a "example.swift" and "example.sks" file for each level. My goal is to save the level that the user is on. Im not saving a high score, I know how to do that. But i'm not sure if its the same. Or how I can apply that it this.

Comment: Why not store an `Int` representing the current level in `UserDefaults`? That's so obvious I'm not sure what your question is actually asking.

Comment: each level is a different file. I want to be able to load the file the user leaves off at when they exit the game

Comment: Then save the current level's filename.

Comment: Would be nicer to use CloudKit to save the game progress. That way users can pick up where they left off across devices. UserDefault will be a local device only solution.

Comment: i can't get it to wok

Comment: @MattYoung Then update your question with what you have tried and clearly explain what issues you are having.

Comment: what would i put in the ("level_file_path") area

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use [UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults).

So, for example, in your `AppDelegate` you would implement this:

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set("level_file_path", forKey: "currentLevel")
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    let levelFilePath = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "currentLevel")

    // load your file/level here
}
```